# Promise { undefined } versus Promise { <pending> }. What is the difference?

Tags: javascript

The following code logs both functions. **testFunc** does not resolved and as a result, the `console.log` outputs `Promise { <pending> }`. **testFunc2** does not return and as a result, the `console.log` outputs `Promise { undefined }`. What is the difference? I am specifically not resolving or returning.

**MDN states the following**:

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.

*Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function*

```
function testFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('I AM A TEST FUNCTION')
  })
}

async function testFunc2() {
  console.log('I AM A TEST FUNCTION 2')
}
console.log(testFunc()) //Promise { <pending> }
console.log(testFunc2()) //Promise { undefined }
```

Is `return new Promise` the same as an async function, without the `.then` method?

Thanks

Comment: Simpler text codes with equivalent results: `console.log(new Promise(() => {}))` and `console.log(Promise.resolve())`.

Comment: @Bergi So the async function just automatically returns Promise.resolve() because there is no return?

Comment: An `async function` returns a promise that will be resolved with the return value of the code. Like a normal function, when there is no explicit `return` statement, that value is `undefined`. Since you did not `await` anything in the function, it will be fulfilled immediately. The result is a promise that looks just the same as `Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise is in a pending state when it hasn't resolved or rejected. That's the case in your `testFunc()`

`testFunc2()` actually resolves right away when you call it, but since you are not explicitly returning anything it resolves to undefined, which is what it's reporting to you.

Changing it to:

```
async function testFunc2() {
    return 'I AM A TEST FUNCTION 2'
}
```

will give you:

```
Promise { 'I AM A TEST FUNCTION 2' }
```

---

EDIT - Regarding comment about not returning:

A function without an explicit `return` still returns and so the promise in the async function still resolves. Consider:

```
async function testFunc2() {
  // no return
}

testFunc2()
.then((r) => console.log("resolved. Value: ", r)) 
// logs: 'resolved. Value:  undefined'
```

To make the original `testFunc` work like the async function, do this:

```
function testFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('I AM A TEST FUNCTION')
      resolve()
    })
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the async function is resolved regardless of if I return from it or not? The MDN quote states that an async function must return to resolve the promise...

Comment: Well it *does* return. It returns undefined, which is what your promise resolves to.

Comment: I see. So an async function resolves regardless of whether there is return or not? testFunc will not resolve without `resolve()`

Comment: @Kainan yes. To make `testFunc` act like `testFunc2`, just add `resolve()` after the `console.log()`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. So would an async function (which returns a promise) be the same as `return new Promise`, except that the later must be resolved, where an async function does not have to return to resolve? Where I struggle is are they in fact the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

An async function *always* returns a promise. If you're not specifically returning something, it'll be `undefined`.

In the first example, you are creating (and returning) a promise, though it never resolves or rejects, so it will forever be pending. In the second example, no promise is created, so it's undefined (it's complete, but with no returned value)